# Add image overlay to pyqtgraph ImageView

Tags: pyqtgraph

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71342255/plot-line-over-pyqtgraph-imageview), but it is about stacking two images in a pyqtgraph.ImageView, with the second one not contributing to the statistics displayed for the first.

The title really kind of says it all.  I have an image that I want to display with all of the nice features of pyqtgraph.ImageView, and that works.  Then I want to highlight areas of that image with an overlay, but I don't want to disturb the histogram.

In my case I have a bitmap of "bad spots"; the main image is monochrome, so I want to paint those bad spots red.

It looks like I could try making a QImage out of my bitmap, but (A) this has proved complicated, and (B) the whole point for me of using pyqtgraph is to *not* have to worry about the underlying Qt interface.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I found this answer -- it was easier than I though.  I can only say that this *did work*, not that it's exactly right.  In particular, this seems to depend on `ImageView.addImage()` adding images in order, from bottom to top -- if I'm wrong (as, for instance, if `addImage` inserts items into a dictionary) then the solution may break the next time I run the code.

The theory is that the original image is on the bottom-most layer, then over that I put my layer with bad pixels painted red.  To make sure I don't just have a black and red image, good pixels are not only black, but transparent.

In the setup code:

```
    self.image_item = ImageItem(image=np.zeros((240, 320)))
    self.image_view = ImageView(imageItem=self.image_item)
    self.image_overlay = ImageItem(image=np.concatenate((np.ones((240, 320, 3)), np.zeros((240, 320, 1))), axis=2))
    self.image_view.addItem(self.image_overlay)
```

In the code that is run each time the image is updated.  Note that `bad_pixels` is a boolean array, the same size as my image, with each bad pixel `True`:

```
    self.image_item.setImage(data.image, autoHistogramRange=True)
    overlay = 255 * (bad_pixels.astype(np.uint8)[:, :, np.newaxis] * np.array((1, 0, 0, 1))[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :])
    self.image_overlay.setImage(overlay)
```